# Extract values between square brackets ignoring single quotes

Tags: python, regex

I am trying the following:

```
s = "Text text text [123] ['text']"
```

This is my function:

```
def getFromSquareBrackets(s):
    m = re.findall(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_']+)\]", s)
    return m
```

But I am obtaining:

```
['123', "'text'"]
```

I want to obtain:

```
['123', 'text']
```

How can I ignore the single quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `'` optional and outside the capturing group

```
m = re.findall(r"\['?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)'?\]", s)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make `'` optional using `?` as

```
>>> re.findall(r"\['?([^'\]]+)'?\]", s)
['123', 'text']
```

---

- `\['?` Matches `[` or `['`.
- `([^'\]]+)` Matches anything other than `'` or `]` and captures them.
- `'?\]` Matches `]` or `']`