# How to build Numpy array from a String written in file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I had to write an array of 1024 dimensional vectors in files, where it is a string.

```
[[[-1.94079906e-03  -2.31655642e-01   2.79239640e-02   1.65049836e-01
    -2.41711065e-02   4.76662189e-01   1.43999630e-03   2.74327975e-02
     1.42574485e-03  -5.95342405e-02   7.44391233e-02  -2.52876729e-01
    -1.00990515e-02  -3.12404502e-02  -3.15531623e-03  -1.05645694e-02
     5.35479194e-05  -2.71148677e-03   1.39582576e-02   1.48318922e-02
     2.73350552e-02   1.10329792e-03   1.87656947e-03   7.87315845e-01
     1.48554507e-03   2.52872050e-01   9.04035103e-03   2.23065093e-02
    -7.66102970e-02  -1.07561275e-02  -8.81098136e-02  -4.76480462e-03
    -4.59164307e-02   9.71463993e-02   5.88618889e-02   1.50974870e-01
     5.95004633e-02  -3.18388380e-02  -7.35895988e-03  -1.16585912e-02
    -1.20033743e-02   2.28719711e-02   1.69246215e-02   4.68009058e-03
     4.62086290e-01   3.05133080e-03   8.51295609e-03   5.41299023e-03
    -3.86441469e-01   5.54564409e-03  -6.44444255e-04  -2.51195673e-03
    -2.19698269e-02  -5.54086491e-02  -9.91180446e-03  -3.82097751e-01
    -6.40135631e-02   5.74917234e-02  -6.93778619e-02  -4.82289121e-02
    -8.80530046e-04  -1.46750783e-04  -7.59039745e-02  -4.49791476e-02
     2.48764846e-02   3.42623852e-02  -1.47593305e-01  -1.06661461e-01
    -4.47107572e-03  -1.18165351e-01  -5.77774234e-02  -1.18526910e-02
     5.31119347e-01   8.07319826e-04  -1.33625632e-02   5.63439801e-02
     1.42297670e-01   8.73860158e-03   2.81544123e-02   4.02801447e-02
    -6.31053932e-04  -2.51916498e-02   7.66465114e-03  -1.44701991e-02
    -2.28392556e-01  -1.52886540e-01  -2.64241938e-02   2.32990598e-03
    -4.51011993e-02  -1.23286285e-01  -2.73374505e-02   4.57140617e-02
    -3.10144224e-03   1.67872999e-02   2.82388210e-01   2.89291646e-02
     1.07920721e-01  -2.94156536e-03   8.14718530e-02   1.23365335e-02
     5.25736660e-02   1.07018501e-01   1.12216305e-02  -6.42671343e-03
    -6.08792575e-03  -2.75880508e-02  -4.29682955e-02   2.29907827e-03
    -1.71477318e-01   1.06728065e-03  -8.91154166e-03  -6.74131513e-02
     1.85923085e-01   6.31039217e-02  -3.01594753e-03  -8.02652538e-03
     2.99957022e-03   3.97651680e-02   7.88619071e-02  -3.88861895e-02
     5.77857941e-02  -2.28491463e-02  -1.84029698e-01   1.88755430e-02
     9.35062673e-03  -7.68110529e-03  -1.34624686e-04  -1.70862395e-02
     2.90840361e-02   3.08215886e-01   9.31615767e-04   8.56576301e-03
    -1.04340032e-01   5.97063676e-02  -5.19387908e-02  -2.51019020e-02
     4.86317575e-02  -9.02486816e-02  -7.01272041e-02  -7.94084519e-02
     3.42463702e-02   1.30526712e-02  -3.89413163e-02   7.12394621e-03
    -7.80236796e-02   6.86016073e-03  -7.09471107e-03  -8.76432285e-04
     2.70982862e-01  -6.52055591e-02  -1.06929066e-02   1.09912697e-02
     5.81025705e-02   5.25720865e-02  -1.09306075e-01  -6.08567521e-02
     1.57058761e-02  -2.72464026e-02  -5.55893872e-03  -1.02705369e-02
     7.71081820e-02   1.22725129e-01  -8.34318772e-02  -1.34621300e-02
     3.10156047e-02  -2.27223411e-02  -2.04452332e-02   8.44530482e-03
     1.39629871e-01   4.65201735e-02  -1.80061292e-02   2.62141787e-02
     1.14859547e-02   3.29010077e-02  -6.33681715e-02  -6.66326750e-03
     2.45806739e-01   6.82016835e-03   1.53852955e-01  -9.26824214e-05
    -2.24408537e-01   3.46144172e-03  -3.13628651e-02   5.43741090e-03
     4.37655784e-02   7.23502412e-02  -2.27418393e-02  -5.73312230e-02
    -9.63647943e-03  -3.06532886e-02  -1.83402985e-01   1.51326170e-03
     7.01990649e-02   5.20174392e-04   3.25092584e-01   8.53244448e-04
    -6.61516309e-01  -2.40109339e-02   7.80446269e-03  -3.96349991e-04
     2.09737703e-01   2.01223418e-02  -3.24580610e-01   1.17111066e-02
    -2.12647036e-01  -1.07400909e-01  -2.13052216e-03   7.19884411e-02
     6.29373044e-02   2.70579964e-01   2.31924746e-03   2.31584962e-02
     6.68760389e-02   6.02776278e-03   1.25936240e-01   9.87441279e-03
    -1.55544477e-02   9.21403050e-01   5.95429866e-03   1.69753373e-01
    -2.77957093e-04  -3.74301686e-03  -8.01488161e-02  -2.92979274e-02
     2.70357099e-03   2.04204336e-01  -2.55553108e-02  -4.37098294e-02
    -9.27719846e-02   3.31938616e-03  -6.86550094e-03  -5.29704131e-02
     4.67646532e-02  -4.76779230e-03  -2.47423232e-01  -1.95020065e-01
    -1.37039032e-02  -2.88726222e-02   4.78997901e-02  -1.67194288e-02
    -2.44984671e-01   4.14241031e-02   2.18765303e-01  -1.29683837e-02
    -1.29538756e-02  -2.40630388e-01  -1.47552008e-03   1.04058897e-02
     8.08705166e-02   2.98772845e-02   1.09445721e-01  -2.72222068e-02
     3.15629435e-03   2.02676475e-01  -5.48119098e-03   1.11927085e-01
    -8.10229045e-04   4.88724336e-02  -2.04598755e-02   7.28014559e-02
    -7.50734936e-03   1.12967454e-01  -1.02381155e-01  -3.93344797e-02
    -5.76012488e-03  -8.27285368e-03   4.68877656e-03   3.56422178e-02
     7.47172013e-02  -4.50611580e-04   3.87510844e-02   5.87241072e-03
     8.89619961e-02   3.71131860e-02  -1.27488390e-01  -2.87959836e-02
     2.09520772e-01   6.84321998e-03  -1.79145802e-02  -4.92445230e-01
    -1.11257724e-01  -3.41908028e-03   4.99965390e-03  -9.43376590e-03
     1.45663433e-02  -1.44766182e-01  -7.85617332e-04   2.50194788e-01
    -1.84243411e-01  -8.52207094e-02   4.91553724e-01   6.98826567e-04
     9.67463851e-02  -9.53106880e-02   1.34932743e-02   9.78818908e-03
     1.42090872e-01  -1.44538991e-02   3.38558876e-03   7.06599429e-02
     1.05294399e-01  -1.04073426e-02   8.84406921e-03  -1.04884133e-02
     1.08525844e-03   2.73697806e-04   5.48925027e-02  -1.37888163e-01
    -7.36754341e-03  -1.68831810e-01  -1.55891664e-02  -1.46280183e-02
    -4.65287874e-03  -4.55598114e-03  -2.31690466e-01   8.52278993e-02
     3.69785540e-02  -5.14281213e-01  -3.15423198e-02   6.99804872e-02
    -6.80299819e-01   5.70312254e-02  -4.68888041e-03   9.24175314e-04
     1.46322310e-01  -2.26290636e-02  -1.17635960e-02  -1.97508056e-02
    -5.63608184e-02  -2.35153502e-03  -3.02714780e-02  -7.00966269e-02
     1.34322822e-01  -5.83322406e-01   6.99004158e-02   6.90660765e-03
    -3.59833129e-02  -4.24275696e-02  -1.13462089e-02   1.26277313e-01
    -2.11074743e-02  -2.75125448e-02  -1.09875022e-04  -1.36324633e-02
    -1.61086857e-01   1.45391980e-03   8.35529938e-02   2.60230571e-01
    -2.66209077e-02  -5.58552158e-04  -6.46227747e-02  -1.03871346e-01
     7.65479207e-02   5.50469197e-03  -8.30342695e-02  -1.41060511e-02
     5.78260748e-04  -7.48543143e-02   4.00875658e-02  -8.43505200e-04
     1.30373640e-02  -3.70042515e-03   2.34432235e-01  -5.03952876e-02
    -8.23894609e-03   5.68602094e-03   2.00182339e-03   2.67363917e-02
    -1.65066063e-01   1.12882899e-02  -2.45540170e-03  -5.58771845e-03
    -3.17897797e-02   3.54408443e-01  -2.19827844e-03   1.96579453e-02
    -2.13856101e-01  -9.39935893e-02  -4.10447363e-03   5.64558394e-02
    -7.74325207e-02   1.12799453e-02   5.74401207e-03   1.17533533e-02
     3.13126147e-01  -9.65978801e-02   4.09295522e-02  -7.19228340e-03
     1.61319543e-02   1.38026938e-01  -1.03539340e-02   2.02257689e-02
    -1.22227691e-01   2.85219820e-03  -1.38053551e-01   1.04186237e-01
    -3.85751538e-02   5.40270396e-02   2.01541111e-02   1.11547910e-01
     8.12843814e-03  -2.46938601e-01   2.63076667e-02   1.17913038e-02
    -3.11973467e-02  -1.92823902e-01   1.21179201e-01  -1.25329243e-02
    -8.06584358e-02   1.80483628e-02  -1.24767497e-01  -9.79684740e-02
     1.42583912e-02  -2.01247111e-01   1.80912524e-01  -7.99218717e-04
     4.43766803e-01  -1.50329890e-02  -5.67825418e-03  -1.08014653e-02
    -5.36615476e-02  -2.61940453e-02  -4.53092828e-02   1.35193672e-02
     4.11850251e-02  -6.01443984e-02  -2.50824913e-02   1.62832197e-02
    -3.54980752e-02   1.94167010e-02   3.73407416e-02  -1.39249265e-02
     1.24431606e-02  -2.71414319e-04   2.07198528e-03  -3.13255489e-02
    -9.13586060e-04  -6.02687523e-03  -2.45338219e-04   3.06239817e-02
     4.73723561e-03  -5.37761077e-02   1.07429676e-01  -3.07083246e-04
     1.83322672e-02   1.11524528e-02  -3.02185658e-02   8.59791264e-02
     1.52892053e-01  -5.19732898e-03   3.35007943e-02  -5.18686930e-03
     4.59660180e-02  -5.97646236e-02  -5.91781130e-03  -9.71765146e-02
    -5.03088348e-03  -2.63293982e-02   2.98104137e-02   1.78570561e-02
    -1.43652499e-01  -9.18011591e-02  -1.30667742e-02   5.08407876e-02
    -1.08531557e-01   4.97847283e-03   8.63077492e-03  -9.12626833e-02
     7.65377134e-02  -1.38562605e-01   1.26607893e-02   2.06802897e-02
    -4.38775197e-02  -1.66922156e-02   1.40064796e-02   4.57174098e-03
    -1.03261333e-03   5.39288446e-02  -2.95640323e-02   3.11757829e-02
    -6.83855964e-03   4.09243908e-03   1.86475474e-04  -5.27539887e-02
    -2.06441600e-02   1.07906722e-02  -3.73281129e-02   4.83028293e-02
     7.07745552e-03   4.19170335e-02   4.73949760e-02  -3.53640225e-03]]

 [[ -8.35226402e-02   9.30680893e-03  -1.19281253e-02   6.61145672e-02
     3.26909008e-03   4.63765323e-01   3.27814883e-03   3.66053022e-02
     1.09708719e-02   7.35405181e-03  -1.55491112e-02   1.80269778e-02
    -3.51096364e-03   3.14430892e-02   1.74052753e-02   5.27430698e-02
     1.55686750e-03   8.57205018e-02  -4.71130945e-03  -1.66305136e-02
    -1.67975724e-02  -3.89260314e-02   6.36396930e-02   7.63485655e-02
    -4.48105129e-04  -6.54933006e-02   2.95349136e-02  -2.45081261e-02
     4.96003777e-02   6.64148927e-02  -2.33270358e-02   3.41189057e-02
     1.60509553e-02  -5.32507300e-02   1.29752964e-01   1.31994952e-03
     7.20134820e-04  -1.98553465e-02  -9.42229573e-03  -1.28459960e-01
     9.08048358e-03  -7.04445392e-02   2.49016993e-02  -2.02601706e-03
     2.32810881e-02   8.85246042e-03  -6.18432183e-03   4.91291285e-02
    -1.68560803e-01  -1.95360109e-01   1.66883413e-02   4.46498543e-01
     8.62153433e-03  -2.90389471e-02  -1.62739735e-02   1.17358692e-01
    -7.42233777e-03   1.05169125e-01   1.42013326e-01  -8.94571014e-04
    -3.26711014e-02  -1.27530540e-03   6.44282848e-02   4.75694202e-02
     1.49227241e-02  -5.22350743e-02   2.38056909e-02   2.92309709e-02
    -2.19096199e-01   1.55504672e-02  -1.53067306e-01   2.74171904e-02
    -7.00602890e-04   6.28591049e-03  -5.55272587e-03  -1.07895516e-01
    -5.65112336e-03  -5.24670519e-02  -4.89811152e-02   5.01033179e-02
     6.93804584e-03   1.05955578e-01  -7.62372569e-04   8.43433514e-02
     4.34672460e-03  -4.59782854e-02   8.87977891e-03  -1.24188691e-01
    -1.83345191e-02   1.53444866e-02  -3.22986394e-02   6.25251094e-04
     9.15350902e-05  -4.84672701e-03  -2.58674123e-03   3.35796690e-03
     4.89366241e-02   4.02635749e-04   1.59860756e-02   7.69474208e-01
     4.08853181e-02   4.34358567e-02   2.25415756e-03   1.78180281e-02
    -1.54250145e-01  -8.23742151e-03  -2.62587331e-03  -5.17571764e-03
    -1.17875308e-01  -2.17287224e-02   2.03241524e-03   3.59281600e-02
     7.83091187e-02  -6.30748495e-02  -4.43855999e-03   1.38513371e-01
    -1.49395345e-02   1.73051998e-01  -1.08843846e-02  -4.09610756e-03
     1.47934854e-01   2.77046226e-02   9.71657410e-03  -4.75595258e-02
    -8.04194286e-02  -6.39762543e-03  -1.78411976e-03  -2.07632020e-05
    -1.20369075e-02  -5.30476645e-02  -2.65281554e-02  -1.27506420e-01
     1.61716379e-02  -1.23544305e-03   5.12566231e-02  -2.99007017e-02
    -2.24648491e-02  -1.08299348e-04  -2.56778561e-02   5.01158787e-03
     1.46491397e-02   8.26944504e-03   9.98148024e-02  -1.25672504e-01
    -1.02828294e-02  -1.48208633e-01  -5.26465550e-02  -1.39929978e-02
     5.14968075e-02  -7.84798432e-03   1.69349450e-03   1.39911417e-02
     9.87590104e-02   8.83786604e-02  -2.10539266e-01   1.15139121e-02
    -2.02425104e-03  -2.96202842e-02   2.34789047e-02  -2.69730925e-03
    -1.28652789e-02  -9.96383606e-04  -1.49479583e-02   2.74939630e-02
     2.21133493e-02   5.40200956e-02  -1.40580133e-01  -1.88481361e-02
     5.64605594e-02   8.01192969e-03   2.08442245e-04  -7.04166517e-02
    -6.91418424e-02   3.14796274e-03   2.43515684e-03   5.66407405e-02
     7.94060528e-03  -9.53438058e-02   1.21964351e-03   1.47800058e-01
    -1.13360971e-01   2.98349423e-05   1.53450280e-01   1.23541877e-02
     7.23110735e-02  -3.53798419e-02   2.02055108e-02   2.04957579e-03
     2.06349175e-02  -3.23418826e-02   1.54947313e-02   3.00867227e-03
     6.27451837e-02  -6.16709888e-03  -4.44535079e-04  -8.95639881e-03
    -9.29646849e-05   4.07954591e-04   1.03105552e-01  -1.26244530e-01
    -1.03752740e-01   7.28853717e-02   1.41500132e-02  -1.69651657e-02
    -7.86132237e-04  -1.02092149e-02  -4.33625951e-02   4.45875973e-02
     3.16701494e-02  -5.97860694e-01  -1.04297372e-02  -3.53601612e-02
    -5.31432092e-01   1.20885514e-01  -4.41514747e-03  -1.37506695e-02
     7.41118193e-02  -1.80932339e-02  -2.18909793e-02  -1.78918764e-02
    -4.53138798e-02  -9.50210169e-03  -2.68109199e-02  -4.37963568e-02
     2.57522136e-01  -1.55035645e-01   8.70719627e-02   2.36497819e-02
     4.50039990e-02  -1.05908541e-02  -6.30994067e-02   5.25860228e-02
     1.30218547e-02  -4.60572615e-02  -1.27857761e-03  -2.23273393e-02
    -1.01790786e-01   3.97628173e-03   4.75442037e-03   1.58620045e-01
    -1.53025975e-02  -5.05035557e-02  -1.91611588e-01  -5.24769202e-02
     2.29781922e-02   1.23675652e-02  -1.08054029e-02  -5.12798950e-02
    -3.13344353e-05   3.84442252e-03   2.34415475e-02  -6.06570218e-04
    -8.98333564e-02   5.93989454e-02   2.30413303e-02  -1.63186044e-02
    -4.73568274e-04   1.26233101e-02  -2.33891979e-02  -3.67069454e-03
    -3.11445054e-02   6.57939492e-03  -7.66414171e-03   8.54648836e-03
    -5.53270467e-02   6.56915456e-02   5.93487732e-02   5.15440246e-03
    -9.67373177e-02  -6.51745126e-02  -3.94938029e-02   5.34577072e-02
    -1.40887564e-02  -3.21616903e-02   4.82407846e-02   2.16054339e-02
     1.52342409e-01  -1.26091624e-02  -3.95356715e-02  -3.49778347e-02
     1.04348501e-02   7.99501091e-02  -5.54051399e-02   1.87601745e-02
    -1.87667310e-01   8.61896726e-04  -3.23137492e-02   5.16451187e-02
     2.22476479e-02  -8.02607462e-03  -2.70199757e-02   5.83411716e-02
     1.13461642e-02  -6.43412471e-02   1.39366373e-01   5.69017865e-02
    -2.33416390e-02  -2.85612494e-01   5.10325246e-02   4.62737009e-02
    -1.91203970e-02   1.32384151e-03  -6.35378435e-02   3.24819842e-03
    -1.32869254e-03   1.75510924e-02   1.41231939e-01   1.28516573e-02
     1.02439635e-02  -4.39045802e-02  -1.10270549e-02   7.96073973e-02
     5.91337262e-03  -7.50695616e-02   1.84723474e-02   9.38338228e-03
    -8.35675339e-04   5.00328392e-02  -4.32583364e-03   1.02049168e-02
    -5.58866095e-03  -4.91249859e-02   5.04319072e-02   4.64591458e-02
    -6.06061965e-02   2.36203405e-03   6.63211709e-03   1.16420723e-02
    -1.95871443e-02  -1.81973800e-02   4.64237249e-03   2.86748866e-03
     5.38999680e-03  -8.34256224e-03   9.33683477e-03  -5.39150741e-03
    -1.86683554e-02   2.48070788e-02   5.92112215e-03   8.56748223e-03
     3.22964415e-02  -5.00624850e-02  -2.52336301e-02   9.17474180e-03
    -8.92325118e-03   4.67876205e-03  -5.74534759e-02   3.73787177e-03
     1.28581151e-02  -1.67223103e-02   7.50076920e-02  -3.98502016e-04
    -1.61230732e-02  -2.75442414e-02   3.94548639e-04  -1.37498451e-03
    -4.96492116e-03   2.53268499e-02   5.55252992e-02  -5.05645424e-02
    -5.79147274e-03  -1.39349727e-02   1.05990777e-02  -4.14465889e-02
     1.90671217e-02   2.38927081e-03   1.91597678e-02   7.26094469e-03
     5.62381647e-05  -3.14109512e-02  -7.03963730e-03   5.72685339e-03
    -4.51433298e-04  -1.14829629e-03   1.45282391e-02  -2.11534575e-02
     1.55422445e-02   5.09766936e-02  -2.77528632e-02  -7.16304639e-03
    -1.41595118e-02  -2.29488108e-02  -2.09072828e-02   2.64024753e-02
     3.75947580e-02   3.53328399e-02   5.87556325e-03  -4.44848882e-03
     3.95338349e-02  -2.64461972e-02   2.43276753e-03  -1.63620003e-02
     3.14164497e-02  -8.08956474e-03   1.49463089e-02   2.09438596e-02
    -8.90694279e-03   3.24987583e-02   6.67429902e-03  -1.50191346e-02
    -1.16796941e-02   3.64522748e-02  -8.61222763e-03   1.09857088e-02
    -3.57604139e-02  -5.16717369e-03   2.68327910e-02   3.17539498e-02
    -1.13831903e-03   2.37232214e-03   8.16115085e-03   6.65428936e-02
     1.27308011e-01   1.32651571e-02  -1.16856256e-03   1.92778313e-03
    -5.13796732e-02   2.23806910e-02   2.64357291e-02  -9.60358977e-03
    -1.81771331e-02  -2.23696785e-04   1.13886436e-02   3.41330506e-02
     2.79273577e-02   3.79165076e-02   2.16118526e-03  -1.12676609e-03
    -2.00524926e-03  -1.37742283e-02  -2.34187655e-02   3.20340917e-02
     2.10321099e-02   4.94092591e-02  -2.68395413e-02   4.29884112e-03
     5.21777458e-02  -3.28805707e-02  -2.18146648e-02   1.72189157e-03
     1.45826461e-02   3.89755853e-02   2.16644220e-02   1.45681109e-02
    -5.07474365e-03   2.73492723e-03   1.24841267e-02   1.98827442e-02
    -5.53916628e-03  -1.07634841e-02   1.36590758e-02  -9.26163197e-02
    -3.95117737e-02  -1.71744905e-03   7.74151552e-03  -1.19977084e-03
    -1.42000178e-02  -3.76450969e-03   2.26605702e-02  -6.73604533e-02
    -2.03648806e-02   3.09449919e-02  -3.69136743e-02   1.27421897e-02
    -1.31009584e-02  -1.37193482e-02   1.25257829e-02   1.81069430e-02
    -8.70318525e-03   2.53016800e-02   4.50089462e-02  -1.51383178e-02
     3.90487462e-02   1.48353223e-02  -5.49035370e-02   1.52793583e-02
     6.09628372e-02   2.26467788e-01  -1.58030409e-02   6.35875948e-03
    -7.22567504e-03   2.31286865e-02   8.45125783e-03   9.40664485e-03
    -7.69937038e-03  -4.84708603e-03  -5.00676176e-03  -1.35368295e-02
    -1.90379925e-03   2.88588181e-02   1.81501191e-02   1.80631205e-02
     1.93565357e-02   5.02644433e-03   6.69117644e-03  -1.11023095e-02
    -1.24723874e-02  -1.13726296e-02   6.56644180e-02   2.00492796e-02
     4.66159452e-03  -3.40204779e-03   1.02386642e-02   2.80533340e-02
    -3.09105241e-03   6.22903183e-03  -4.17059404e-04   2.77249347e-02
    -4.01747860e-02   2.38689836e-02   4.76544015e-02   3.70072108e-03
     1.06910598e-02  -2.36127879e-02   3.88308056e-02   2.19260529e-03
    -3.29560637e-02  -2.21122336e-02  -4.79903491e-03   1.51326843e-02
    -3.50229093e-03   2.24676784e-02   1.43503872e-04  -3.17934118e-02
    -1.51474942e-02   2.43635513e-02   1.99209489e-02   1.78901535e-02
    -2.50796489e-02  -3.82525399e-02  -7.11742649e-03   1.94894355e-02
    -2.41929526e-03   3.09266243e-02  -3.60688046e-02   1.30333030e-03
    -1.69621110e-02  -4.34306217e-03   3.22814146e-03   1.35722384e-02
    -3.22210952e-03   6.81779860e-03   5.64415827e-02  -4.67799557e-03
    -3.43072243e-05   1.47441979e-02   1.27382390e-02   2.21132208e-02
     1.00761396e-03   5.81906037e-03  -2.46797632e-02   2.25442611e-02
     5.67185059e-02   1.56729892e-02  -1.27938166e-02  -4.06436957e-02
    -7.34348316e-03   4.15970478e-03   5.33090569e-02   2.27547772e-02
    -4.65768166e-02  -8.26780498e-03  -1.76717900e-02   1.14618763e-02
    -6.11296529e-03  -9.91329923e-03  -1.77789368e-02   1.49894347e-02
     2.00315397e-02   4.59903367e-02  -9.15393308e-02  -1.06830876e-02
    -3.23898084e-02  -1.45315717e-03  -1.91982687e-02   5.13540730e-02
     5.07519208e-03   1.16187809e-02  -7.04900697e-02   1.31804580e-02
     9.46480874e-03   1.66993719e-02   9.73339472e-03   4.89528617e-03
     1.25560202e-02   9.88730043e-03   2.34009465e-03  -1.93884056e-02
     1.21425718e-01   1.60742402e-01   1.74952727e-02  -2.61049587e-02
     2.36830972e-02  -2.52299607e-02  -3.02438326e-02   1.08230580e-02
    -1.32970130e-02  -4.28082272e-02  -1.06386631e-03  -1.67271737e-02
    -2.24054903e-02   2.09099753e-03   9.29628033e-03  -1.35044642e-02
     5.04099466e-02  -2.71457713e-02   1.73648577e-02   2.48547047e-02
    -1.89860701e-03   1.70966927e-02  -2.60377172e-02   4.39567082e-02
     7.85375014e-04   1.94283966e-02  -1.33992946e-02  -2.70982515e-02
     1.87142137e-02   3.46861593e-03   3.57702821e-02   2.04772372e-02
     1.90474056e-02   4.41925647e-03  -7.10287225e-03   1.49543295e-02
     1.38295190e-02   2.13973895e-02   2.09906921e-02   6.11540861e-03]]]
```

I am trying to extract it using regex (or any other method if possible).

So far I tried solutions like [Extract values between square brackets ignoring single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601759/extract-values-between-square-brackets-ignoring-single-quotes) but they are not working.

How could I extract these arrays and use them as numpy vectors?

Comment: Why did you write them that way?  I warned you in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453828/numpy-array2string-just-writing-in-string that those brackets would complicate loading.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, only np.array2string method worked simple str() again wrote ... in place of real values

Comment: Both `array2string` and `str()` include the brackets.   Neither is recommended if you want easy parsing.  If you didn't have the brackets you could simply `split` the string on the delimiter, and make an array from the resulting list of strings (with appropriate `dtype` specification).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [numpy.fromstring()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) method to accomplish this task once you have read-in the file's contents. Below is a quick and dirty implementation of this (no error detection), which works with your example array.

```
import numpy as np

with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    arr = np.fromstring(f.read(), np.dtype(np.float), 1024)
```

Comment: @tstseby To fix the problem simply change the number at in the last field of the function call be the expected size of the resulting array or you can just leave it blank if each matrix is in its own file. Sorry, I misread the problem statement.

Comment: yes, I have many vectors in that string, all of the same dimensions though, putting their size at the end will stil create only one array of that size, right?

Comment: Yes, it will only create one.

Comment: You could potentially split up the resulting array into smaller arrays of a given size.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html

Answer (score 0):

This would also get you there, using regular expressions:

```
import numpy as np
import re

with open("somefile.txt") as f:
    content = f.read()
content = re.sub('[\[\n\]]', '', content)
arr = re.split(r'\s+', content)
np_arr = np.array([float(i) for i in arr])
```